# How to get parameter value of sql from shell script

Tags: sql, shell

I use a shell script to run sqlite3 command, the code is as below:

```
idd=0;
/usr/bin/sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/NotificationCenter/*.db <<SQL_END
select app_id from app_info where bundleid='com.myapp.main';
select last_known_path from app_loc where app_id=29;
SQL_END
```

i want to get the last_konwn_path of the sql, and i want to transfer a paramter instead of using '29', any one can help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation, the mechanism replacing variables in doubly quoted strings, happens in here-documents. You can thus wrap your call in a function as follows:

```
# notificationdb_last_known_path APP_ID
notificationdb_last_known_path()
{
  local APP_ID
  APP_ID="$1"
  /usr/bin/sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/NotificationCenter/*.db <<SQL_END
  select app_id from app_info where bundleid='com.myapp.main';
  select last_known_path from app_loc where app_id=${APP_ID};
  SQL_END
}
```

You can then call this function like this to store answer in a variable:

```
my_app_id=$(notificationdb_last_known_path 29)
```

**Factorize the sqlite invocation**
If you have several similar database accesses, it is worthy to factorize the sqlite invocation as follows:

```
# notificationdb_session()
{
  /usr/bin/sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/NotificationCenter/*.db
}

# notificationdb_last_known_path_query APP_ID
notification_last_known_path_query()
{
  local APP_ID
  APP_ID="$1"
  cat <<SQL_END
  select app_id from app_info where bundleid='com.myapp.main';
  select last_known_path from app_loc where app_id=${APP_ID};
  SQL_END
}

# notificationdb_last_known_path_query APP_ID
notificationdb_last_known_path()
{
  notificationdb_last_known_path_query "$1" | notificationdb_session
}
```

**Do not store variables**
In shell programming it is *much easier* to pass structured data around as data flows between processes as to pass it through variables.  Programs `sort`, `cut`, `paste`, `join` and `awk` are especially useful when working on structured data streams.

**Disable text interpolation in here-documents**
If you need to disable text interpolation in a here-document, you can achieve this by writing the here-document delimiter between single-quotes as in

```
cat <<'SQL_END'
SQL_STATEMENT
SQL_END
```